# SQL Server trigger - SET NORESULTS ON?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

How do I hide results from trigger?

Is there a SET NORESULTS ON? or similar?

I have a instead of insert trigger I have 2 selects like this

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpFinal FROM INSERTED WHERE pID is not NULL
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM INSERTED WHERE pID is NULL
```

The problem is that when I am doing an INSERT that triggers the trigger in the result windows I see the result of that 2 selectd from the trigger...

I want to inhibit that similar of what SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF is doing for the rowcount

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

This is the full code

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_eElementDef1Insert] ON [dbo].[eElementDef1]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT * INTO #tmpFinal FROM INSERTED WHERE pID is not NULL
    SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM INSERTED WHERE pID is NULL

    DECLARE rows_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #tmp

    OPEN rows_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM rows_cursor
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @entDef bigint
        DECLARE @pID bigint
        --SET @entDef = (SELECT aDefinition FROM tDefinition WHERE cDefinition=SUBSTRING('eElementDef1',2,LEN('eElementDef1')-1))
        SET @entDef=1
        EXEC NewInstance 0, @entDef, @pID OUTPUT
        UPDATE #tmp SET pID=@pID
        INSERT INTO #tmpFinal SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #tmp
        DELETE TOP(1) FROM #tmp
       FETCH NEXT FROM rows_cursor  
    END   
INSERT INTO eElementDef1 SELECT * FROM #tmpFinal

drop table #tmp
drop table #tmpFinal
CLOSE rows_cursor   
DEALLOCATE rows_cursor
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

the big problem is that pID is my PK

The NewInstance SP looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewInstance]
  @version bigint,
  @entdef bigint,
  @Identity int OUT
AS
INSERT INTO tInstanceKey (pEntityDefinition) VALUES(@entdef)
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

It has Insert in it so it can not be transformed into a function....

Comment: Neither of the statements you've shown should be producing an output rowset. It may help to show the entire trigger.

Comment: Danger, danger! `SELECT TOP 1` and `DELETE TOP(1)` are *not* guaranteed to target the same row.

Comment: Yap I know... but I do not know other solution...

Comment: YIKES! Cursor inside a trigger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your cursor properly, and it's the FETCH NEXT FROM line that's returning a result set.

Hopefully, there's a Primary Key on this table. You'd want to add something like this:

```
DECLARE @PK bigint
```

Change your cursor definition:

```
DECLARE rows_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT PKColumn FROM #tmp
```

Change your FETCH statements (both):

```
FETCH NEXT FROM rows_cursor into @PK
```

And change these also:

```
    UPDATE #tmp SET pID=@pID WHERE PKColumn = @PK
    INSERT INTO #tmpFinal SELECT * FROM #tmp where PKColumn = @PK
    DELETE FROM #tmp where PKColumn = @PK
```

If you've got a multi column primary key, obviously you'll have to expand all of these, and add more variables.

Also, it would be better if we could avoid the cursor entirely - How complex is the NewInstance stored proc, and where else is it used?

---

Based on UPDATEs. What you want is something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_eElementDef1Insert] ON [dbo].[eElementDef1]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT * INTO #tmpFinal FROM INSERTED

    WHILE EXISTS (select * from #tmpFinal where pID is NULL)
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @entDef bigint
        DECLARE @pID bigint
        SET @entDef=1
        EXEC NewInstance 0, @entDef, @pID OUTPUT
        UPDATE TOP 1 #tmpFinal SET pID=@pID where pID is null
    END   
INSERT INTO eElementDef1 SELECT * FROM #tmpFinal
END
```

Comment: the big problem is that pID is my PK